# kivy FitImage: TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, kivy

```
    def preview(self):
    return FitImage(source=self.module.get("preview"),size_hint_y=.35, \
      pos_hint={"top": 1}, radius=[36, 36, 0, 0])
```

but then i get TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize) when i add this widget. What part of the code is inducing this error? Thanks!

Comment: Is `FitImage` your own class? If it is, could we see it? If not, did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: Hello, it's from KivyMD. I found out the problem is radius... The documentation is here: https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/kivymd/utils/fitimage/?highlight=image#module-kivymd.utils.fitimage. I still don't know why radius doesn't work here:(

Comment: I would intuitively expect a `radius` value to be a single number. What are you expecting that list to mean?

Comment: radius at each corner? that's how they did that in the documentation though...

Comment: Mm, I don't think I can help, then. It sounds like you have a legitimate case for a bug report, or at least to contact the devs.